# Inspection forms software that reference questions dynamically?

Tags: forms, maintenance, inspection

I'm looking for low-code/no-code software to create inspection forms for our maintenance team.
We have about 90 different types of inspections split into 5 different maintenance programs. Each inspection contains a minimum of 10 question that needs to be filled out by our team, resulting in about 900 questions that need to manage, updated, etc.

Around 300-400 of these questions are used in multiple inspections. I'm therefore looking for a solution that allows me to manage the questions separately where the forms/templates reference them dynamically.

This approach would allow me to reuse questions across multiple forms without having to duplicate them, which saves time and reduce the risk of errors. Additionally, if I need to make changes to a question, I only have to modify it in one place, and the changes will be reflected in all the forms that use it.

I've scoured the internet for an out-of-the-box solution but have not been able to find anything.

Any help would be appricited!